# Перевод Binding из XAML в код

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Помогите мне пожалуйста перевести в код вот этот Binding из XAML : `Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=dockPanel}`.

Мой XAML :

```
<ListBoxItem Content="Это строчка :D" FontWeight="Bold" Height="50" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=dockPanel}"/>
```

Мой код :

```
ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = new ListBoxItem();
myListBoxItem.FontWeight = System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold;
myListBoxItem.Height = 50;
myListBoxItem.Width = SetBinding(Width, dockPanel.Width);
myListBoxItem.Content = "Моя строчка :D";
this.mylistbox.Items.Add(myListBoxItem);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Binding` в коде создаётся так:

```
myListBoxItem.SetBinding(
    ListBoxItem.WidthProperty,
    new Binding("Width") { Source = this.dockPanel });
```

Но есть шанс, что вам это не нужно на самом деле. Лучше не создавать item'ы вручную (у нас же в конце концов не WinForms), а положить *данные*, которые вы хотите отобразить, в `ItemsSource`, и настроить `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: не переживайте, всё работает, спасибо :D

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Вот и хорошо :) Пожалуйста!